# DeleteById Not working in Spring boot JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities- **User** and **Notes**. One User can have multiple Notes. I am trying to implement a soft delete for both the tables. For the User table, it is working fine but for Notes table, calling deleteById is not changing the value of the deleted column to true. I tried returning findById(notesId) and it's returning right row but delete is not working.

```
package com.we.springmvcboot.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

import antlr.collections.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
@SQLDelete(sql = "Update User set deleted = 'true' where UserID=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = 'false'")//FALSE
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long UserID;
    
    @Column(name="emailid")
    private String emailID;

    @Column(name="deleted")
    private String deleted="false";
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<Notes> usernotes;
    
    public User() {}

    public User(String emailID) {
        super();
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }

    public String getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(String deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public long getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(long userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getemailID() {
        return emailID;
    }

    public void setemailID(String emailID) {
        this.emailID = emailID;
    }


    public Set<Notes> getUsernotes() {
        return usernotes;
    }

    public void setUsernotes(Set<Notes> usernotes) {
        this.usernotes = usernotes;
    }

}
```

```
package com.we.springmvcboot.Model;
    

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Notes")
    @SQLDelete(sql = "Update Notes set deleted = 'true' where NotesID = ?")
    @Where(clause = "deleted = 'false'")
    public class Notes {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long NotesID;
        
        @Column(name="title")
        private String title;
        
        @Column(name="message")
        private String message;
        
        @Column(name="date")
        private String date;
        
        @Column(name="deleted")
        private String deleted="false";

        @Column(name="label")
        private int label=1;


        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "UserID", nullable = false)


        private User user;

        
        public Notes() {}
        


        public Notes(String title, String message, String date, User user, int label) {
            super();
            this.title = title;
            this.message = message;
            this.date = date;
            this.user = user;
            this.label=label;
        }


        public Notes(long notesID, String title, String message, String date, int label) {
            super();
            NotesID = notesID;
            this.title = title;
            this.message = message;
            this.date = date;
            this.label=label;
        }


        public String getDeleted() {
            return deleted;
        }

        public void setDeleted(String deleted) {
            this.deleted = deleted;
        }

        public int getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        public void setLabel(int label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public long getNotesID() {
            return NotesID;
        }


        public void setNotesID(long notesID) {
            NotesID = notesID;
        }


        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }


        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }


        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }


        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }


        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }


        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }



        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

            
    }
```

```
package com.we.springmvcboot.Service;

import com.we.springmvcboot.Model.*;
import com.we.springmvcboot.exception.*;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import com.we.springmvcboot.Repository.NotesRepository;
import com.we.springmvcboot.Repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class TodoService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userrepo;

    @Autowired
    NotesRepository notesrepo;


  
    public Object deleteNote(Map<String, Object> input) throws InvalidInputException, NoteNotFoundException {
        long userID;
        try {
            userID = ((Number) input.get("userID")).longValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("Missing UserID");
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        long notesID = ((Number) input.get("notesID")).longValue();

        System.out.println(notesID);

        if (!notesrepo.findById(notesID).isPresent())
            throw new NoteNotFoundException("Invalid Notes ID");
        
       **notesrepo.deleteById(notesID);**


        map.put("status", 200);
        map.put("message", "Request Successful");
        map.put("data", null);
        return map;
    }


    public Object deleteUser(Map<String, Object> input) throws NoteNotFoundException {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        long userID;
        userID = ((Number) input.get("userID")).longValue();
        if (!userrepo.findById(userID).isPresent())
            throw new NoteNotFoundException("Invalid User ID");
        userrepo.deleteById(userID);
        map.put("status", 200);
        map.put("message", "Request Successful");
        map.put("data", null);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it's not the reason but your `@SQLDELETE`  on User is `UserID=?`, while on Notes is `NotesID = ?` (whitespace difference)

Comment: @limido I have tried removing the space. But it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@NamedQuery` instead of `@SQLDelete`
or
try with
`repo.deleteInBatch(list)`